# Gurobi902 with c++

Tags: c++, ubuntu-18.04, gurobi

I am using Gurobi902 on ubuntu 18.04.4 and I am trying to compile a .cpp file from the examples provided in the packadge with g++, but I am having the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccN61kwy.o: In function `main':
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x4da): undefined reference to `GRBEnv::GRBEnv(bool)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x4fa): undefined reference to `GRBModel::GRBModel(GRBEnv const&)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x541): undefined reference to `GRBModel::set(GRB_StringAttr, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x597): undefined reference to `GRBModel::addVars(double const*, double const*, double const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*, int)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x5db): undefined reference to `GRBModel::addVars(double const*, double const*, double const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*, int)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x5ff): undefined reference to `GRBModel::set(GRB_IntAttr, int)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x629): undefined reference to `GRBLinExpr::GRBLinExpr(double)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x69c): undefined reference to `operator*(double, GRBVar)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x6b5): undefined reference to `GRBLinExpr::operator+=(GRBLinExpr const&)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x73c): undefined reference to `GRBQuadExpr::GRBQuadExpr(GRBVar, double)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x76e): undefined reference to `GRBQuadExpr::GRBQuadExpr(GRBLinExpr)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x78e): undefined reference to `operator==(GRBQuadExpr, GRBQuadExpr)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x7ae): undefined reference to `GRBModel::addConstr(GRBTempConstr const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x823): undefined reference to `GRBModel::optimize()'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x8c9): undefined reference to `GRBQuadExpr::GRBQuadExpr(double)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x8f4): undefined reference to `operator+(GRBVar, GRBVar)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x90d): undefined reference to `GRBQuadExpr::GRBQuadExpr(GRBLinExpr)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x92d): undefined reference to `operator<=(GRBQuadExpr, GRBQuadExpr)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x94d): undefined reference to `GRBModel::addConstr(GRBTempConstr const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x9b6): undefined reference to `GRBModel::optimize()'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x9f2): undefined reference to `GRBModel::~GRBModel()'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0xa85): undefined reference to `GRBEnv::~GRBEnv()'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0xdce): undefined reference to `GRBModel::~GRBModel()'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0xe8c): undefined reference to `GRBException::getErrorCode() const'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0xec4): undefined reference to `GRBException::getMessage[abi:cxx11]() const'
/tmp/ccN61kwy.o: In function `printSolution(GRBModel&, int, int, GRBVar*, GRBVar*)':
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0xfea): undefined reference to `GRBModel::get(GRB_IntAttr) const'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x101f): undefined reference to `GRBModel::get(GRB_DoubleAttr) const'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x1098): undefined reference to `GRBVar::get(GRB_DoubleAttr) const'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x10d4): undefined reference to `GRBVar::get[abi:cxx11](GRB_StringAttr) const'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x111a): undefined reference to `GRBVar::get(GRB_DoubleAttr) const'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x11b0): undefined reference to `GRBVar::get[abi:cxx11](GRB_StringAttr) const'
diet_c++.cpp:(.text+0x11f6): undefined reference to `GRBVar::get(GRB_DoubleAttr) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

do you have any suggestions?

Comment: did you try the sample makefile?

Comment: yes, I run the Makefile, and it works. Now when I tried to run it again, I have:               make: Nothing to be done for 'c++'.

Comment: That sounds like the compilation went fine. Please check whether you can run the created binary.